# MPMoviePlayerController never stops loading

Tags: ios, xcode, video, mpmovieplayercontroller

Having trouble with MPMoviePlayerController. When I attempt to load the video I just get the activity indicator ir the navbar and it says loading. You see the controllers at the bottom, so the controller loads just not the video. I have copied the link into a browser and the video plays fine. I am using the same code from the app that is already up in iTunes, I am just revamping it. So when I click on the videos in the app that is in iTunes the videos work fine. Just not sure what is going on now here is my code:

```
-(void)loadVideo {

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:self.videoUrl];
NSLog(@"url %@", self.videoUrl);
self.movie = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                           object:self.movie];

self.movie.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
self.movie.shouldAutoplay = YES;
[self.view addSubview:self.movie.view];
[self.movie setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];

}

- (void) moviePlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification {
    MPMoviePlayerController *player = [notification object];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     removeObserver:self
     name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
     object:player];

    if ([player
         respondsToSelector:@selector(setFullscreen:animated:)])
    {
        [player.view removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue. When I used the property self.videoUrl it was a string that had the @"" still attached. I needed to strip that from the string so only the url was left.